# How to set DateTime as ValuesAttribute to unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I want to do something like this

```
[Test]
public void Test([Values(new DateTime(2010, 12, 01), 
                         new DateTime(2010, 12, 03))] DateTime from, 
                 [Values(new DateTime(2010, 12, 02),
                         new DateTime(2010, 12, 04))] DateTime to)
{
    IList<MyObject> result = MyMethod(from, to);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count);
}
```

But I get the following error regarding parameters

> An attribute argument must be a
>   constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE:** nice article about Parameterized tests in NUnit 2.5
http://www.pgs-soft.com/new-features-in-nunit-2-5-part-1-parameterized-tests.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An alternative to bloating up your unit test, you can offload the creation of the TestCaseData using the TestCaseSource attribute.

TestCaseSource attribute lets you define a method in a class that will be invoked by NUnit and the data created in the method will be passed into your test case.

This feature is available in NUnit 2.5 and you can learn more [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5)...

```
[TestFixture]
public class DateValuesTest
{
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(DateValuesTest), "DateValuesData")]
    public bool MonthIsDecember(DateTime date)
    {
        var month = date.Month;
        if (month == 12)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private static IEnumerable DateValuesData()
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(new DateTime(2010, 12, 5)).Returns(true);
        yield return new TestCaseData(new DateTime(2010, 12, 1)).Returns(true);
        yield return new TestCaseData(new DateTime(2010, 01, 01)).Returns(false);
        yield return new TestCaseData(new DateTime(2010, 11, 01)).Returns(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Just pass the dates as string constants and parse inside your test.
A bit annoying but it's just a test so don't worry too much.

```
[TestCase("1/1/2010")]
public void mytest(string dateInputAsString)
{
  DateTime dateInput= DateTime.Parse(dateInputAsString);
  ...
}
```

Comment: (Be careful with your locale)

Comment: Quick and dirty, but I like it.

Answer (score 5):

Define a custom attribute that accepts six parameters and then use it as

```
[Values(2010, 12, 1, 2010, 12, 3)]
```

and then construct the necessary instances of `DateTime` accordingly.

Or you could do

```
[Values("12/01/2010", "12/03/2010")]
```

as that might be a little more readable and maintainable.

As the error message says, attribute values can not be non-constant (they are embedded in the metadata of the assembly). Contrary to appearances, `new DateTime(2010, 12, 1)` is not a constant expression.