# NUnit parameterized tests with datetime

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Is it not possible with NUnit to go the following?

```cs
[TestCase(new DateTime(2010,7,8), true)]
public void My Test(DateTime startdate, bool expectedResult)
{
    ...
}
```

I really want to put a `datetime` in there, but it doesn't seem to like it. The error is:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
> or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Some documentation I read seems to suggest you should be able to, but I can't find any examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set DateTime as ValuesAttribute to unit test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344679/how-to-set-datetime-as-valuesattribute-to-unit-test)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I'd probably use something like the [ValueSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=valueSource&r=2.5) attribute to do this:

```cs
public class TestData
{
    public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }
    public bool ExpectedResult{ get; set; }
}

private static TestData[] _testData = new[]{
    new TestData(){StartDate= new DateTime(2010, 7, 8), ExpectedResult= true}};

[Test]
public void TestMethod([ValueSource("_testData")]TestData testData)
{
}
```

This will run the TestMethod for each entry in the _testData collection.

Comment: This is a great answer and works well.  However, it's 2018 now, and for developers just stumbling upon this, it should be noted that using nameof() is preferable to the string literal.  So you'd simply have: [ValueSource(nameof(_testData))]TestData testData

Comment: Also note that, when having many `TestData` the `TestMethod` is not called for any more test cases at first fail. This behaviour differs from `TestCase` where all test cases are run.

Answer (score 180):

You can specify the date as a constant string in the `TestCase` attribute and then specify the type as `DateTime` in the method signature.

NUnit will automatically do a `DateTime.Parse()` on the string passed in.

Example:

```cs
[TestCase("01/20/2012")]
[TestCase("2012-1-20")] // Same case as above in ISO 8601 format
public void TestDate(DateTime dt)
{
    Assert.That(dt, Is.EqualTo(new DateTime(2012, 01, 20)));
}
```

Comment: This seems to use American format only when using slashes. If like me, you live outside the States, you can use this format "2014-12-25"

Comment: This is great. Seems as if it does not work for `DateTime?`, though!?

Comment: By far the simplest solution

Comment: Following up on @Robert Brooker's comment, the "2014-12-25" format works within the U.S. too.

Comment: @PaulKertscher time has passed... and it works for `DateTime?` params too. At least for Nunit 3.12.0

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs Good to know :) Not too long though, I think. Anyway, 7 years is like a billion years in technology-years, init?

Comment: Works for me, locally i'm gmt but devops uses a US format, passes in both environments

Answer (score 13):

Another alternative is to use a more verbose approach. Especially if I don't necessarily know up front, what kind of `DateTime()` (if any...) a given string input yields.

```cs
[TestCase(2015, 2, 23)]
[TestCase(2015, 12, 3)]
public void ShouldCheckSomething(int year, int month, int day)
{
    var theDate = new DateTime(year,month,day);
    ....
}
```

...note `TestCase` supports max 3 params so if you need more, consider something like:

```cs
private readonly object[] testCaseInput =
{
    new object[] { 2000, 1, 1, true, "first", true },
    new object[] { 2000, 1, 1, false, "second", false }
}

[Test, TestCaseSource("testCaseInput")]
public void Should_check_stuff(int y, int m, int d, bool condition, string theString, bool result)
{
....
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use the TestCaseData Class as documented: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5.9

In addition to specifying an expected result, like:

```cs
 new TestCaseData(12, 4).Returns(3);
```

You can also specify expected exceptions, etc.:

```cs
 new TestCaseData(0, 0)
    .Throws(typeof(DivideByZeroException))
    .SetName("DivideByZero")
    .SetDescription("An exception is expected");
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that NUnit doesn't allow the initialization of non-primitive objects in the TestCase(s). It is best to use [TestCaseData](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData).

Your test data class would look like this:

```cs
public class DateTimeTestData
{
    public static IEnumerable GetDateTimeTestData()
    {
        // If you want past days.
        yield return new TestCaseData(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).Returns(false);
        // If you want current time.
        yield return new TestCaseData(DateTime.Now).Returns(true);
        // If you want future days.
        yield return new TestCaseData(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)).Returns(true);
    }
}
```

In your testing class you'd have the test include a [TestCaseSource](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) which directs to your test data.

How to use: TestCaseSource(typeof(class name goes here), nameof(name of property goes here))

```cs
[Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(DateTimeTestData), nameof(GetDateTimeTestData))]
public bool GetDateTime_GivenDateTime_ReturnsBoolean()
{
    // Arrange - Done in your TestCaseSource

    // Act
    // Method name goes here.

    // Assert
    // You just return the result of the method as this test uses ExpectedResult.
}
```

Comment: Introducing dependencies like `DateTime.Now` in your unit tests is not good by the way. You'd better use a stub

Answer (score 2):

Nunit has improved and implicitly tries to convert the attribute arguments.
See doc: [NUnit3 Doc - see note](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcase.html)

This works:

```
[TestCase("2021.2.1", ExpectedResult = false)]
[TestCase("2021.2.26", ExpectedResult = true)]
public bool IsDate(DateTime date) => date.Date.Equals(new DateTime(2021, 2, 26));
```

Take care to use english culture format for DateTime string arguments.

Comment: Yeah this causes issues when using a hosted pipeline like devops, github actions as the date format is likely to be US and a different culture to your local dev env.